# In the manifest file package file are allowed any hypen or charecter

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi in my android app package name is example.eu-gb.example.net.In the android manifest file when I am going to change the route name it shows an error ,but when I delete the hypen from the package name it shows no error .
So is the  hypen(-) are not allowed in the manifest file ,anyone please let me know .
Immam

Comment: I think you answered your own question when you removed the hyphen. Why don't you Google for "Java package naming conventions"?

Comment: See my answer below @user2489898

Answer (score 0):

According to official JAVA documentation, if the `hyphen` occurs in your domain name(package name), you should convert them to an `underscore`!

**Go below for official link :**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Hope this helps you!